# How make work a Picker with an ObservedObject in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to get a list of Datacenters from a Rest API and show them in a Picker, so the user can choose one. When I do it with a static list it works fine. However, retrieving the Datacenters dinamically seems not to work fine.

I'm using Xcode 11 (GM)

This is the Datacenter Object

```swift
struct Datacenter:Codable, Hashable, Identifiable{ 
    let id: String
    var location: String
}
```

This is the ObservedObject (it has the property datacenters that is an array of Datacenter objects)

```swift
@ObservedObject var datacenters_controller : DatacentersController
@State private var selectedDatacenter = 0
```

This was my first attempt:

```swift
Picker(selection: $selectedDatacenter, label: Text("Datacenter")) {
   ForEach(0 ..< datacenters_controller.datacenters.count) {
     Text(self.datacenters_controller.datacenters[$0].location)
   }
}
```

Swift complained with the following error:

```
ForEach<Range<Int>, Int, Text> count (4) != its initial count (0). `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data. Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an explicit `id`!
```

Then I switched to:

```swift
Picker(selection: $selectedDatacenter, label: Text("Datacenter")) {
   ForEach(datacenters_controller.datacenters) { datacenter in
      Text(datacenter.location)
   }
}
```

It "works" (no error), but the result is not the expected because although I can select a datacenter, it is not "stored", not shown in the Picker as selected.

Actual result

[image: Picker without selection]

Expected result

[image: Picker with a datacenter selected]

Any idea? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your post doesn't include the definition of `DatacentersController`. Perhaps the error is there. Did you remember to put `@Published` in front of `var datacenters` in `DatacentersController`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The DatacentersController works fine. When I click on the Picker Datacenter, I see the different Datacenters. The problem is that, although I select one, it is not shown after the selection

Comment: You say “The DatacentersController works fine”, but you don't know why your view isn't working. So how do you know the controller works fine?

Comment: Because of two things. If I debug, I see that the variable DatacenterController.datacenters has the datacenters (obtained from the Rest API). And because if I click on the Picker, I see all datacenters, and I can select any of them. The problem is that after selecting one, I don't see it in the Form.

Comment: The error `ForEach<Range<Int>, Int, Text> count (4) != its initial count (0)` (from your first attempt) seems likely to be caused by the `ObservedObject` changing without notifying. The problem in your second attempt is (as described by LuLuGaGa) that you have omitted the `tag` modifier from your pickable views. The type of `selectedDatacenter` must also match the type of whatever values you use as your tags (which presumably will be either `String` or `Datacenter`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a working example. The key is that selectedDatacenter needs to be the same type as Datacenter.id (in this case, String).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var datacenters_controller = DatacentersController()
    @State private var selectedDatacenter = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Picker(selection: $selectedDatacenter, label: Text("Datacenter")) {
                    ForEach(datacenters_controller.datacenters) { datacenter in
                        Text(datacenter.location)
                    }
                }

                // Just here for demonstration
                Text("selectedDatacenter (id): \(selectedDatacenter.isEmpty ? "Nothing yet" : selectedDatacenter)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the supporting code

```
struct Datacenter:Codable, Hashable, Identifiable{
    let id: String
    var location: String
}

class DatacentersController: ObservableObject {
    @Published var datacenters: [Datacenter] = []

    init() {
        datacenters = [
            Datacenter(id: "ABQ", location: "Albuquerque"),
            Datacenter(id: "BOS", location: "Boston"),
            Datacenter(id: "COS", location: "Colorado Springs")
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing tag on your picker:

```
Picker(selection: $selectedDatacenter, label: Text("Datacenter")) {
   ForEach(datacenters_controller.datacenters) {
     Text($0.location).tag($0)
   }
}
```

Apple docs on tag:

> Sets the tag of the view, used for selecting from a list of View
>   options.

Comment: It didn't work :( The result is the same. No error, I can see the datacenters after clicking on the Picker, but after selecting one, it is not "stored" or "shown" as selected.

Comment: FWIW, the `tag` is not needed. You only need if if you’re not using whatever the collection is identified by.

Answer (score 2):

In your second attempt, you need to use the `tag` modifier (as described by LuLuGaGa). You also need to change the type of `selectedDatacenter` to match. For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init(_ controller: DatacentersController) {
        self.datacenters_controller = controller
        self._selectedDatacenter = State(initialValue: controller.datacenters[0].id)
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Picker(selection: $selectedDatacenter, label: Text("Datacenter")) {
                    ForEach(datacenters_controller.datacenters) {
                        Text($0.location).tag($0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @ObservedObject private var datacenters_controller: DatacentersController
    @State private var selectedDatacenter: String
}
```