# swiftUI picker "Generic struct 'Picker' requires that 'String' conform to 'View'"

Tags: swift, swiftui

I followed the accepted answer to this link

[How make work a Picker with an ObservedObject in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57912601/how-make-work-a-picker-with-an-observedobject-in-swiftui)

but I get the message "Generic struct 'Picker' requires that 'String' conform to 'View'" in the struct GameListPicker

```
import SwiftUI

struct GameListPicker: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var gameListViewModel = GameListViewModel()
    @State private var selectedGameList = ""
    
    var body: some View {
     Picker(selection: $selectedGameList, label: ""){
            ForEach(gameListViewModel.gameList) { gameList in
                Text(gameList.gameName)
            }
        }
     .onAppear() {
            self.gameListViewModel.fetchData()
            }
    }
}
```

The GameListViewModel

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class GameListViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var gameList = [GameListModel]()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchData() {

        db.collection("GameData").addSnapshotListener {(querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
          print("No documents")
          return
        }

        self.gameList = documents.map { queryDocumentSnapshot -> GameListModel in
          let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
          let gameName = data["GameName"] as? String ?? ""
            return GameListModel(id: gameName, gameName: gameName)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

and the gameListModel

```
import Foundation

struct GameListModel: Codable, Hashable,Identifiable {
    
    var id: String
    //var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var gameName: String
    
}
```

I can't determine the problem

Comment: To proceed by steps, could you replace             Text(gameList.gameName)
with             Text("Some Text").   If that "works", then initialize String with var gameName: String = ""

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should provide a parameter that conforms to `View` protocol for the argument `label:` in `Picker`.

Replace:

```
Picker(selection: $selectedGameList, label: "") {
```

With:

```
Picker(selection: $selectedGameList, label: Text("")) {
```

Comment: Thanks. your answer and pawello2222's answer worked

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a text you can use:

```
Picker("Some text", selection: $selectedGameList) { ...
```

If you don't want to have any labels for your picker (as you tried to use `""`) you can use an `EmptyView`:

```
Picker(selection: $selectedGameList, label: EmptyView()) { ...
```

Comment: Thanks. your answer and Frankestein's answer worked